Mapping to array of enum in doctrine
I got a enum and a column that store an array of enums
CREATE TYPE my_enum AS ENUM('value1', 'value2');

CREATE TABLE my_table(
    // other columns
    my_enums my_enums[]
)

On my entity, I try this mapping
class MyTable 
{
   #[ORM\Column(type: Types::[ARRAY|SIMPLE_ARRAY|JSON], enumType: MyEnum::class)
    protected ?array $myEnums = null;
}

But I got an issue in the insert. I never got to got format {myvalue1,myvalue2}
I don't found how to map this correctly.
Edit:
This is the errors, i got :

with the type array

"hydra:description": "Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\ReflectionEnumProperty::Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\{closure}(): Argument #1 ($item) must be of type BackedEnum, string given",


with the type simple_array
I got this query

INSERT INTO my_table (id, my_enums) VALUES (4, 'first');

"hydra:description": "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  malformed array literal: \"first\"\nDETAIL:  Array value must start with \"{\" or dimension information.\nCONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $2 = '...'",


and with the type json

"hydra:description": "Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\ReflectionEnumProperty::Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\{closure}(): Argument #1 ($item) must be of type BackedEnum, string given",


What "issue" do you get? Please [edit] your question and include all details like error messages. Maybe this also should get a [mcve] or other explanation how you run that code / cause the issue.
